# PyTorch Dataloader - list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I have implemented a COCO dataset as follows:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from detr.datasets.coco import CocoDetection


class MyCoco(CocoDetection):
    def __init__(self,
                 img_folder,
                 ann_file,
                 transform=None) -> None:

        super().__init__(img_folder, ann_file, transform, return_masks=True)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img, target = super(MyCoco, self).__getitem__(idx)
        return img, target
```

Then I defined a batch sampler and dataloader as follows:

```
my_coco = MyCoco(
        settings.datasets.img_folder,
        settings.datasets.ann_file
)

sampler_train = torch.utils.data.RandomSampler(my_coco)
batch_sampler_train = torch.utils.data.BatchSampler(sampler_train, 
                                                    batch_size=32, 
                                                    drop_last=True)

data_loader_train = DataLoader(my_coco, 
                               sampler=batch_sampler_train,
                               collate_fn=collate_fn, 
                               num_workers=1)
```

When I try to iterate the loader there is an error:

```py
for a in data_loader_train:
    print(a)
    break
```

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Looking into the functions themselves, for some reason the indexes are within another list, and i dont understand why, and more importantly, how to how to fix it:

[image]

Comment: Could you try changing `sampler=batch_sampler_train` by `batch_sampler=batch_sampler_train` (when you create the DataLoader)?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal runnable example that recreates the issue?

Comment: @Laideen your solution worked! thanks! - feel free to post it as an answer and i'll upvote and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataLoader class of PyTorch has many arguments, some of them are incompatible.

As you have already defined the batch sampler, you need to pass it as `batch_sampler` instead of `sampler`. The sampler expects to find indices, not batches of indices.

Then, the code would be:

```
data_loader_train = DataLoader(my_coco, 
                               batch_sampler=batch_sampler_train,
                               collate_fn=collate_fn, 
                               num_workers=1)
```

Another way to do it is passing the `sampler_train` sampler and the batch size as arguments of the DataLoader:

```
data_loader_train = DataLoader(my_coco, 
                               sampler=sampler_train,
                               batch_size=32,
                               drop_last=True,
                               collate_fn=collate_fn, 
                               num_workers=1)
```